# What does "overcome" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'm trying to understand the following bolded sentences. These have been copied from a legal document regarding the outcome of a patent application linked [here](https://jade.io/article/587203/section/777?asv=gloss_widgets).

> DECISION
>
> **The sole outstanding objection to application 2013204646 has been
> overcome.**  I accept the patent request and complete specification
> relating to that application.
>
> **The objection of manner of manufacture in relation to application
> 2013204658 has been overcome.**  Pursuant to regulation 13.4(1)(g), the
> application will not lapse for failure to gain acceptance until 3
> months from the date of this decision.  Aristocrat has the remainder
> of that period in order to address the objections of lack of inventive
> step.

What is "overcome" referring to here? Is the sentence saying that the "objection of manner of manufacturer" has succeeded or failed?

I'm confused since overcome is defined as the following by Google.

> overcome (verb)
>
> - succeed in dealing with (a problem or difficulty).
> - defeat (an opponent)

Comment: The objection has been "defeated".  The associated problem has been solved.

Comment: Think about the literal etymology; you "came over" (overcame, derived from overcome) something. Does that not sound like you defeated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- > What is "Overcome" referring to here?

the objection mentioned in the document

- > [Has] the" **objection** of manner of manufacturer" succeeded or failed?

It has failed.

**overcome**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Overcome)

> (tr) to **surmount** (triumph over) obstacles, objections, etc